# Keyboard not showing when TextFormField is pressed Flutter

Tags: flutter, keyboard, hidden, textformfield

The keyboard is not displayed when clicking on TextFormField on virtual machines and real machines like Oppo, Redmi.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvcpT.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngGBg.jpg)

Comment: Did you wrap textformfields with Form widget?

Comment: Can you please post some sample code.

Comment: Can you please post your text form field code to your question

Comment: Thank you. I added android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in android manifest then fix issue.